# .Will accdb Access Database Work with Visual Studio 2019 x86?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, visual-studio-2019

What does it take to use an .accdb format Microsoft Access database in Visual Studio 2019 x86? Whenever I modify and test the connection, I get the error message "The Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB provider cannot be used in Visual Studio because it is either 64-bit only or not installed." However, when I use an identical .mdb format database, it works fine. The only difference is the Database file I refer to.

[Test Connection Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cI0l.jpg)

Comment: The `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` or `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0` come in x86 and x64 versions. If your app is 32bit (is there a specific reason?), you need to use the x86 driver. If  you have installed (in the development machine) the x64 version of, e.g., the `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` Provider, you need to install the x86 version of the `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0` Provider (or the other way around): you cannot have the x86 an x64 version of the same Provider installed in the same System. -- Or, build an app that targets `AnyCPU` and you can use the available Provider (JET included).

Comment: If you must target x86 because of dependencies, COM stuff or other, then you need a version of the Provider that matches the bitness of your app.